What is the most efficient vba code to duplicate an excel worksheet and paste as another tab in the same workbook as values for documentation purposes
I am seeking a solution to efficiently duplicate an excel tab and paste into the same workbook as values for documentation purposes. Below is the current code I could come up with but I am finding it takes over a min to complete and hoping there is a quicker solution. Any suggestions would be helpful and thank you in advance.
Sub copy_paste()

    Application.screenupdating=false
    Application.calculation=xlcalculationmanual
    Application.cutcopymode=false
    
    ‘Copy sheet and paste as second tab and use A1 as tab title’
    Dim wks As worksheet  
    Set wks=activesheet
    Wks.copy before:= shtDeskEP (2nd excel tab)
    
        If wks.range(“a1”).value<>”” then
            On error resume next
            Activesheet.name=wks.range(“a1”).value
    
        End if
    Application.screenupdating=false
    Application.calculation=xlcalculationautomatic
    Application.cutcopymode=true

End sub


A minute is a long long time to copy a single tab.  What's on the tab being copied?  If you calculate the full workbook how long does it take?

To duplicate the active sheet as values:
Option Explicit

Sub copy_paste()
  Dim r
  r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  Sheets.Add(before:=shtDeskEP).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(r, 1), UBound(r, 2)) = r
End Sub

UPD
If you need "to keep the same formatting as the original tab, keep rows/columns that were originally hidden, hidden and, also, rename the tab title after cell A1 of the original tab" and to keep values only as requested in a comment:
Sub copy_paste1()
  Dim r, os As Worksheet, rg As Range
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    Set os = ActiveSheet
    With Sheets.Add(before:=Sheet2) ' shtDeskEP
      With .Cells(1, 1)
        r = os.UsedRange
        .Resize(UBound(r, 1), UBound(r, 2)) = r
        os.UsedRange.Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
      End With
      For Each rg In os.UsedRange.Columns
        .Columns(rg.Column).Hidden = rg.Hidden
      Next
      For Each rg In os.UsedRange.Rows
        With .Rows(rg.Row)
          .Hidden = rg.Hidden
          .RowHeight = rg.RowHeight
        End With
      Next
      Dim name$, i&
      name = os.[A1]: i = 0
      On Error GoTo RenameErr
Rename:
      .name = name
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
  End With
  Exit Sub
RenameErr:
  i = i + 1
  name = Left$(os.[A1], 31 - Len(CStr(i)) + 2) & "(" & i & ")"
  Resume Rename
End Sub

UPD
The test of 'copy_paste1' on 2500x61 with numbers, texts, formulas and various formatting takes about a second.


Oh my that worked perfectly! Duplicated the tab in 3 secs. Can I please ask if you can amend the code to keep the same formatting as the original tab, keep rows/columns that were originally hidden, hidden and, also, rename the tab title after cell A1 of the original tab?

Can you test copy_paste1? It copies values same as copy_paste then copies formats. I guess it's the most time-consuming operation. If performance will be satisfactory, the sub can be developed further to adjust rows and column visibility and other staff.

I am running into a 424 run time error on the os.usedRange.copy code. Any idea why?

Do you run the sub as is?

How big is your worksheet (rows, columns used)?

Columns out to BI and rows vary but 2500

Performed a test on 2500x61 with numbers, texts, formulas and various formatting. 'copy_paste1' takes about a second.

The sub did work as is. If there are columns and rows hidden and a list filtered in original tab. How can the tab be pasted so they remain hidden and filtered?

Actually I got it to work by replacing the .pastespecial codes to: .pastespecial xlpastecolumnwidths .pastespecial xlpasteformats (sorry typing on phone). Anyway we can amend the code so that if we happen to have a situation where the duplicated tab might have the same name it would still use the name but would have a number at the end?

You could use something like:
Sub DuplicateSheetsAsValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    
    ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculations to improve speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Create a duplicate sheet
        ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        
        ' Reference the new sheet
        Set newWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        
        ' Rename the new sheet with a suffix to avoid duplicate names
        newWs.Name = ws.Name & "_Copy"
        
        ' Paste values only
        newWs.UsedRange.Value = newWs.UsedRange.Value
    Next ws

    ' Restore settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Thank you for the time on this code. It did have to stop it after it took longer than two minutes. I appreciate it nonetheless.

Copy Data Efficiently!?
Sub BackupValues()
    
    Dim WasSuccess As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the 'before' sheet.
    Dim bsh As Object: Set bsh = shtDeskEP ' code name
    
    ' Reference the 'source' worksheet.
    ' If it's always the same, reference it by name or code name.
    Dim ssh As Object: Set ssh = wb.ActiveSheet
    If Not TypeOf ssh Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "Sheet """ & ssh.Name & """ is not a worksheet!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    Dim srg As Range:
    With ssh.UsedRange
        Set srg = ssh.Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
    
    ' Retrieve the potential 'destination' worksheet name.
    Dim dName As Variant: dName = ssh.Range("A1").Value
    If IsError(dName) Then
        MsgBox "The cell with the new sheet name holds an error value!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Len(dName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The cell with the new sheet name is blank!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    dName = CStr(dName) ' e.g. "123"
       
    ' Check if the name is available.
    Dim dsh As Object:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(dName)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "A sheet named """ & dsh.Name & """ already exists!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Insert/reference a new worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(Before:=bsh)
    
    ' Attempt to rename it.
    Dim WasSheetRenamed As Boolean:
    On Error Resume Next
        dws.Name = dName
        WasSheetRenamed = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    If Not WasSheetRenamed Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
           dws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox """" & dName & """ is not a valid sheet name!", _
            vbExclamation
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell.
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    ' Copy formatting.
    srg.Copy
    dcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    dcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Goto dcell
    
    ' Copy values.
    dcell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
    
    WasSuccess = True
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error in continuation
        If Not ssh Is Nothing Then ssh.Activate
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        If WasSuccess Then
            MsgBox "Values backed up.", vbInformation
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


Wow! This was instant. The only thing it is missing is hiding rows that were originally hidden, keeping a list filtered if filtered on original tab and hiding guidelines. This is absolutely what I am looking for.

I added .EntireRow when referencing the source range and it kept hidden rows, hidden, and filtered items, filtered.

Thanks for sharing. I had no clue that this could work. I've always copied the whole worksheet without issues. Did you figure out why the latter takes so long in your case?

Im sorry what is the latter part that you are referring to? With your code, it runs in 20secs.

By the latter part I mean that your code is copying the whole worksheet which you said would take a minute or so. You said my code would take no time. Does your entire row implementation use 20s?

Thats correct. I am asking for help on one part of a bigger code.

How would you amend the code to use numerical values at the end if a tab exists already. For example, if cell A1 says “package” and i run the code it will save the new tab as Package but if I run it again I would want it to say “package 2”.

You would need to use a Do Loop and iterate through an amended code similar to the part that starts with Dim dsh... and ends with the message box. Best ask a new question. Put a constant at the top of a new sub, e.g. Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Package", add the rest of the code replacing dName with the constant, and accurately explain what you need and what you have tried.
